# How to add a Locator to a Manipulate / ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, programming

I have the following Manipulate to graphically show the n-th roots of unity:

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[Map[ReIm[#[[1, 2]]] &, Solve[z^n == 1, z]], AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {n, 2, 128, 1}]
```

Now, I want to change the z^n == 1 to z^n == p[[1]] + I * p[[2]] where p comes from a Locator.

How do I have to change the above Manipulate so that I can add a Locator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Manipulate[ListPlot[Map[ReIm[#[[1, 2]]] &, Solve[z^n == pt.{1, I}, z]], 
   AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
 {n, 2, 128, 1}, {{pt, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. ( I thought that I had tried that but got an error message..., anyway it does work now. )

Comment: @nilo, my pleasure.